# Can't set title of highchart through @input

Tags: angular, highcharts

I initialize my Highcharts like this:

```
export class StreamsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() platform: string = "";
  @Input() title: string = "";

  series: any[] = [];

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFlag: boolean = false;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    title: {
      text: this.title
    },
    chart: {
      zoomType: "x",
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime",
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "",
      },
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },

    series: this.series,
  };
...
```

Later I populate this.series in a service callback with this.updateFlag = true; This all works fine.

But the title isn't set and remains empty.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this)
 ...
```

When I check the object in ngOnInit(), the title has the content like I wanted, but it isnt visible in the Graph. When I just put a random string in, it is visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is `chartOptions` take the initial value from `@Input() title:=''`, but when `title` gets later input from parent its not updating in `chartOptions`.

Comment: Put on OnChanges in there to check if the title via de input has changed and use the setTitle call to dynamically update: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart?_ga=2.36744425.874065285.1633183650-326826712.1633183650#setTitle

Comment: Thank you both. 

@MikeOne could you provide a snippet how to do that? I'm a bit lost here.

Thanx.

Comment: Try setting title using setter `@Input() set title(value: string) {
    if(value){
       this.chartOptions.title.text = value;
       // Or using setTitle, i think here your HighChart Ref is this.Highcharts
       // this.Highcharts.setTitle({ text: value});
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are initialising chartOptions directly in the component class, the input title will not work.

You need to initialise the chartOptions in ngOnInit lifecycle method. I have made a sample stackblitz to show this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-gaekp1?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts